# What exactly does the Normal node do?

Tags: node-editor

The Blender manual page doesn't give too much information. It has a sphere to change **a** direction. What direction does it change exactly? I understand that normals are vectors perpendicular to mesh faces, but I just can't figure out how normals work inside the node editor. When I rotate the Normal node sphere, is it changing normal DIRECTIONS? How do I predict the result? I'm so baffled by this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Normal** node outputs a *normalized* vector (`(X,Y,Z)`), meaning a vector with a length of **1**. The ball represents the direction of the normal, *like you were looking down on it from the top of the 3D Viewport*.

Therefore, the default output of the **Normal** node is `(0,0,1)`, or directly up. When you rotate the ball, you are changing the output normal, as if you were looking at it from the top, so **+X** is to the right, and **+Y** is towards the top of your screen.

[image]

If you choose to plug something into the *Normal* input, the *Dot* output will give the dot product of the input normal and the normal represented by the ball.